# Best algorithm and data structure to compare two big lists

Tags: java, collections, compare

Everyday I receive one list of 30-40k lines, each line contains meaningful or meaningless names like fastcar, ultrafastcar, blablablacar etc.

I also have one big list which consists of the all words in any language (about 50k lines).

And i want to compare first list against second in order to filter which includes(or starts with - ends with) the words from the second list. I mean If word "ultrafastcar" then it will not be filtered but "blablacar" will be filtered out.

I have prepared some Java codes but it takes too long to compare lists. I have used ArrayLists and compared them with contains(), startsWith() methods. Are ArrayLists correct choice and what else algorithm can i use to compare them except these methods.

Comment: 50k is not big, you should be able to do this fair quickly.  Look at ArrayList and `parallelStream()` to easily add some concurrency (it uses fork join under the hood).

Comment: is your list of words sorted? If so are you using a binary search? A hash map might be quicker than a list.

Comment: Second list (dictionary words) is sorted. I didn't try binary search.

Comment: Putting words in a tree so you can do a fast lookup would probably make this much faster. And how many words? If it's one word a line, that's very little. The slow part will be the prefix/postfix checking.

Comment: HashSet for the second list

Comment: This, you don't need a sorted list for the second set, use a hash to make look up faster.  No wonder it "takes too long."  That one should have been obvious.

Comment: Does hash set set really help you here, given that OP is looking for substrings? [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick) sounds more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing a ternary search tree with the second list and then check if the words in the first exist in the tree.